# Does it make sense to have a static global variable in a header file?

Tags: c++, global-variables, header-files, linkage, one-definition-rule

Static variable has file scope. Say I have two following files:

- file1.h
- file1.cpp
- file2.h
- file2.cpp

I have declared static variable say `static int Var1` in both the header files. Both `file1.h` and `file2.h` are included in `main.cpp` file.

I did this since the static variable will have file scope so it won't conflict each other.
But after compilation I found it is showing conflict.

Now static variable is behaving like a `extern` variable. On the other hand if I declare the static variable in both .cpp files, it compiles well.

I am unable to understand this behavior.

Can any body explain how scope and linkage are working in this scenario.

Comment: Related, see [Do not define an unnamed namespace in a header file](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/DCL59-CPP.+Do+not+define+an+unnamed+namespace+in+a+header+file)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Static variables are local to the compilation unit. A *compilation unit* is basically a `.cpp` file with the contents of the `.h` file inserted in place of each `#include` directive.

Now, in a compilation unit you can't have two global variables with the same name. This is what's happening in your case: `main.cpp` includes `file1.h` and `file.h`, and each of the two headers defines its own `Var1`.

If logically these are two distinct variables, give them different names (or put them in different namespaces).

If these are the same variable, move it into a separate header file, `var1.h`, and include `var1.h` from both `file1.h` and `file2.h`, not forgetting the [#include guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in `var1.h`.

Comment: You have provided the best and simplest definition of a _compilation unit_ that I've ever found: "A _compilation unit_ is basically a .cpp file with the contents of the .h file inserted in place of each `#include` directive."

Answer (score 17):

Static variables have translation unit scope (usually a `.c` or `.cpp` file), but an `#include` directive simply copies the text of a file verbatim, and does not create another translation unit. After preprocessing, this:

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
```

Will turn into this:

```
/* file1.h contents */
static int Var1;

/* file2.h contents */
static int Var1;
```

Which, as you know, is invalid.

Comment: My thiniking was there will be two compilation unit.Thanks for clearing by doubts

Answer (score 3):

Assuming static variable `static int Var1` is at global scope in both the headers and included both the headers in `main.cpp`. Now, first the pre-processor copies the content of included files to the `main.cpp`. Since, at `main.cpp` there is `Var1` declared twice at the same scope, multiple declaration error will arise. ( i.e, one copied from `file1.h` and the other form `file2.h` by the pre-processor)

Each source file is compiled individually. Now, when you declare seperately in their source files, each source file is unaware of existence of the other static variable present in the other source file bearing the same name. So, compiler don't report an error. You can mark it as extern, if you want a variable to be shared among the source files.